# I cannot understand the point of this simple code

Tags: c, typedef, adt, abstract-data-type

I am doing this assignment, and there are some stuff (from start-up materials) that I cannot comprehend.

```
typedef enum
{
    NORTH,
    EAST,
    SOUTH,
    WEST,
    NUM_POINTS
} Point;

typedef Point Course[NUM_POINTS] ;
```

I don't get the idea behind the last line , and how can I use it in the code?

Comment: http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter8/typedef.html  Some extra reading on typedef

Comment: Woah, this looks like code from CircleMUD!  Didn't think I'd see anything like this again in the wild.  Fond memories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
typedef a b;
```

Makes `b` an alias for type `a`, e.g.

```
typedef int foo;

int bar;
foo bar;
```

both `bar`s are equivalent. In your case,

```
typedef Point Course[NUM_POINTS] ;
```

Makes `Course` an alias for type `Point[NUM_POINTS]` (where `NUM_POINTS == 4`), so

```
Course baz;
Point baz[NUM_POINTS];
```

are equivalent.

Comment: I kinda got your point.

So what does Point[4] exactly mean?

If Point was a structure then I would get, but it's an 'enum'.

Excuse my ignorance.

Comment: An enum is just an int under the covers. So it's making you an array of integers.

Comment: @M4design: An array of 4 `Point`'s. You could think an `enum` as an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

an enum starts at 0 and increases by 1 for each value.

So you have: `NORTH = 0`, `EAST = 1`, `SOUTH = 1`, `WEST = 3`, `NUM_POINTS = 4`

`NUM_POINTS` is set to the number of items in the enum.

The last line creates an alias of Course for a point array with 4 elements in it.  The syntax is a little confusing because the array subscript is after `Course` and not next to `Point`.

```
typedef Point Course[NUM_POINTS] ;
```

However it does work the same way as for example:

```
int x[10];
```

The `[10]` part is next to the variable name not the type.

Comment: I know that, I just don't get how or why would we use the last line.

I feel like I should explain more, should I :) ?

Comment: Well, the number of items you are intended to *use*. Not an uncommon idiom, and very slick when its a good idea.

Comment: @M4design: Was still writing as you wrote that, please recheck might make more sense now.

Answer (score 3):

Since `NUM_POINTS` is the last entry in the enum, it has the highest value, and is the count of the other values. If `NUM_POINTS` is not meant to be used as an actual value for a Point, it looks like the purpose of the last line is to create a type name for an array of points of size equal to the number of "real" points.

Here's one nice feature: if you add more values to the enum (like `NORTH_EAST`, `SOUTH_WEST`, etc.) **before** `NUM_POINTS`, the typedef line will automatically still be correct, because the value of `NUM_POINTS` will have grown because of the new values inserted before it.

Answer (score 0):

It means that Course can be used to represent an array of Points, with NUM_POINTS being the number of items in the array.